# Nginx Location Blocks

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

We have this following nginx configuration,

```
map $http_user_agent $is_desktop {
        default 0;
        ~*iPhone|iPod|iPad 1;
#       ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce|phone) 0;
        ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce) 0;
        ~*spider|crawl|slurp!bot 1;
        ~*windows|linux|os\s+x\s*[\d\._]+|solaris|bsd 1;

}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /home/ubuntu/application/api_project/api_app/templates/static;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

       location /sitemap.xml {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/sitemap;
           index  sitemap.xml sitemap.xml;
       }
       location /robots.txt {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/robots;
           index robots.txt robots.txt;
       }


    location /api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/application/api_project/api.sock;
    }

    location / {
                if ($is_desktop = 1) {
                        proxy_pass https://example.com;
                        break;
                }

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;     
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
        }
}
```

We recently added the /API block but because of this API response is very very slow and also getting 502 bad request lot of times. We are struggling on this from yesterday and not able to find the solution. What is the issue here? Please help.